# Tailwind text over image without using absolute position

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Is there any better way to put the text over the image without using absolute position? I'm having a hard time fixing it on medium/small screens. I tried to look for other similar questions on StackOverflow but they are not in Tailwind.

[Here's the image I'm trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpeOt.jpg). Just the image with the text over it on the right side.

Here is what I tried, which kind of works. It's not bad on large screens and small screens. I'm just having issues with medium screens.

```
<div className="p-10">
    <div className="relative">
      <span className='flex justify-center md:block '>
        <img className='w-2/3 sm:w-2/4 ' src={p} alt=''/>
      </span>
      <h1 className="relative sm:text-5xl  text-2xl text-white md:bottom-[35rem] md:left-[40%]  left-24 overflow-hidden">
            Photography <br /> helps people <br /> to see.
      </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please correct me if I'm doing it wrong, or if there is a better way! Thank You

Comment: FYI: Nesting `h1` in `span` is not allowed in HTML to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is to overlay content with grid instead.

This [article](https://css-tricks.com/positioning-overlay-content-with-css-grid/) covers it very nicely. But it has more symmetry than the design you showing there.

If you can put what you have achieved so far in a play.tailwind I can take a look and suggest something. but hopefully the article can give the idea.
But [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/qDqcZfKJau) is an idea of how to something similar without absolute positioning.